# Necesito Sustituir los nombres de cierta longitud por otro nombre dado

Tags: java, array

Tengo ciertos nombres con diferentes longitudes y necesito cambiar los de una cierta longitud por otro.

Por ejemplo la matriz da 5 nombres: Juan, Pedro, Joaquin, Luis y Rafa.

El usuario ingresa la longitud de caracteres del nombre (en este ejemplo 4) y el nuevo nombre por el que cambiar (en este caso, Pepe).

Entonces todos los nombres con longitud 4 (Juan, Luis,Rafa) deben de ser sustituidas por Pepe.

Tengo unas vagas ideas pero no entiendo como realizarlo, me seria de mucha ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Debes demostrar que intentaste y donde fallaste.

Answer (score 1):

No es complicado, solo tienes que comparar las longitudes de los string que hay en el array y si coinciden con lo que has introducido, cambias:

```
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[]listaNombres = {"Juan", "Pedro", "Joaquin", "Luis", "Rafa"};
        int longitud;
        String cambio;

        System.out.println("Introduce la longitud");
        longitud = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre a cambiar");
        cambio = in.readLine();

        for(int x = 0 ; x < listaNombres.length ; x++)
        {
            if(listaNombres[x].length() == longitud)
            {
                listaNombres[x] = cambio;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Por favor, no conteste preguntas donde el usuario no ha intentado nada. Siempre se debe demostrar un intento de algun tipo. Si no, estas haciendo sus tareas por ellos.